# Spring boot admin 2.0.4 email notification not working with basic configuration

Tags: notifications, spring-boot-admin

spring boot admin2.0.4 email notification is not working with just email settings in .yml file. Do we need to configure a java mail sender separately for this. As er code centric documentation it says, just adding email configuration should work...

Add spring-boot-starter-mail to your dependencies:

Configure a JavaMailSender

2) application.properties

spring.mail.host=smtp.example.com
   spring.boot.admin.notify.mail.to=admin@example.com

http://codecentric.github.io/spring-boot-admin/2.0.4/#mail-notifications

Answer (score 0):

I moved on to SBA 2.1.0 and it started working like a charm with above specified config only. Thanks